# prevent using javascript in window.location

Tags: javascript, window, location, xss

I have a page which redirects to a url from parameters in query string like:
**page.html?redirectUrl=index.html**
Inside the page i have code like this:
**window.localtion.href = redirectUrl;**

It is requiements to use redirect url by parameters. The page contains secure sensitive data. Someone can make the url with javascript like:
**page.html?redirectUrl=javascript:alert(document.getElementById("password").value)**
and secure data can be stolen.

How to prevent bypass javascript code to window.localtion.href?

Comment: By who would the data be stolen in this case? The user? They can get any data on the page anyway.

Comment: @Pekka웃 — The user (Alice) can follow a link to Bob's site from Malory's (the attacker) site. This is a classic XSS attack.

Comment: I'd step back and look at the problem the redirect is trying to solve in the first place. You might be able to check submitted URLs against a database or a pattern.

Comment: @Quentin Good idea if you have a fixed list of URLs. I'm not sure there exists a pattern for XSS attack, though. It would be too simple, now wouldn't it? Note that even Facebook struggles with it.

Comment: @Slava you might want to read this: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19432

Comment: Other options would be to use a server side script to read the query string, parse the submitted URL as a URL (e.g. with [`URI::URL`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI::URL)), check that it is an HTTP or HTTPS URI, and then error if it isn't. Even that exposes you to the risk that you'll be used as a layer of redirection by spammers though.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would work as long as you're not redirecting with it:

Javascript:

```
var field = document.getElementById("redirectUrl");
var newValue = String(field.value);
alert(newValue);
```

Basically, using the String constructor to "sanitize" the input.

These will probably help more with other cases:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Overall, I would recommend NOT using Javascript to sanitize input. If you're handling really sensitive or important data you are highly recommended to use a server-side language to validate and sanitize your input.

Answer (score 1):

You might try putting the URL in an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement) and checking the protocol:

```
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.href = redirectUrl;

if(anchor.protocol != "javascript:") {
    window.localtion.href = redirectUrl;
}
```

However, I'm not sure how good the browser support is for this, since MDN lists it as an HTML5 feature.